# choosing the checkboxes in the same line

Tags: jquery, checkbox, row

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sevketpolan/r56e6L42/)

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"/></td><td><input type="checkbox"/></td><td><button>Toggle</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"/></td><td><input type="checkbox"/></td><td><button>Toggle</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"/></td><td><input type="checkbox"/></td><td><button>Toggle</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

When I click on the ''toggle button'', I want to choose and unchoose the checkboxes in the same line. 
How can I do that? Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var checkboxes = $(this).parent().siblings().children();
        checkboxes.prop('checked',!checkboxes.prop('checked'));
    })
})
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n05vzx6h/1/)

Comment: @Anton A downvote was a bit too much if you ask me. The comment would be ok. :-) I did do my research after your comment though and i changed my answer accordingly. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Anton At least you got into trouble to give a reason for the downvote, that lead me to do the research, so i improved myself. Nothing is in veign after all.

Comment: I was on a lunch break, i saw that you updated your answer but it's  still using `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/r56e6L42/3/)

```
$('button').click(function(){
   var chbox = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
   $.each(chbox, function(i,k){
      if($(k).is(':checked'))
         $(k).prop('checked',false);
      else
         $(k).prop('checked',true);
   });
});
```